# How to detect multiple browser tab on same java application

Tags: java, session, browser, right-click, stripes

Good day,

For example, mostly in banking website. After user log in to the website, the website normally will prevent the user to right click and open in new tab.

User still can copy the url and paste it into new tab and browse it. And I saw some of the banking website will automatically log the user out if user doing this.

Would like to know how the system detect the user browsing the same application in new tab. (I am doing Java Web Application using Stripes framework)

Kindly advise.

Comment: Don't do that.  It's stupid and pointless.

Comment: @SLaks, yes, I know that is stupid, I know developer wont do this. But we cant tell user not to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005372/disable-right-click-and-copy-paste-etc-from-my-web-page

Comment: @rev_dihazum, this post is talking about disable right click, view page source. Mine is detect duplicate tab on same browser.

Comment: @PanadolChong , I gave an approach to solve duplicate tab.You could see that.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless Protocol, session and cookies can't help you with your goal.
I suggest you to try websocket or other way to make a comet type communication with clients.

Answer (score 0):

To disable duplicate Tab, one approach would be like this:

- For valid credential from Login page, add hidden `<input name="tabId">` field cotaining a tab Id (something Random number generated at server side) to home Page.
- After login, for each request send hidden `<input name="tabId">` field value as current Tab id.
- Each time a  request came, you have to find the value of hidden `<input name="tabId">` field, if the value is null/blank then redirect it to Login Page.

Comment: Hi, its quite hard for me to change the exsiting design. If I change the type of communication to AJAX, it affected whole system.

Comment: @PanadolChong, I have modified my answer with another approach. see this and feedback me.

Comment: I am still not so understand. First step and second step I can get it. At the third step, do u means that If I browse the same url in another tab, it will send request with blank tab id value?

Comment: @PanadolChong 3rd point: for each request you have to find the value of ``<input name="tabId">`` is blank or not? if blank then you treat it a new TAB request