# disable paste (control V) in IE for an input text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to disable the paste (control V) into a text box using javascript/jquery for IE?

I do not have access to the markup unfortunately or I would use onPaste="return false". Can it be attached with Jquery?

If it cannot be disabled at least is there a way to detect it so that when the paste event occurs just remove the text from the input text box.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="" size="25" value="Enter letters here" name="TEXTBOX___97___470GCPC___31" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$('input[name="TEXTBOX___97___470GCPC___31"]').bind('paste', function(){return false;})
```

There is no need to use jQuery though, as you could just set the `onpaste` handler.

```
var input = document.getElementsByName('TEXTBOX___97___470GCPC___31')[0];
if (input)
   input.onpaste = function(){return false;};
```

Note that this event may not fire on some browsers (e.g. Opera). Also, see this question: [*Disable Copy/Paste into HTML form using Javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-copy-paste-into-html-form-using-javascript) on why you should *not* disable pasting.

Comment: Duh, why didn't I think of that. I looked and the events that could be used in Jquery doc http://api.jquery.com/bind/ and http://api.jquery.com/category/events/ and didn't see it so I thought it didn't support it. I should of tried it first. THX

Comment: Thanks for the added info but I only needed it for IE as the other script I am using for input validation seems to take care of the other browsers just not IE for some reason

Comment: Firefox didn't get the `paste` event until version 3.0.