# how to detect copy and paste in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have two fields, one is `emailid` and another is `password` in my form. I want to prevent the user from pasting into those fields. They should be forced to enter manually, like Google Forms.

Comment: If someone wants to copy and paste, that's their decision, not yours. Preventing default OS/browser behaviour is *never* an acceptable solution.

Comment: It's been done before, but it's a bad idea, especially for emails and other plain text: it's more inconvenient than occasionally typing the wrong email address.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-copy-paste-into-html-form-using-javascript

Comment: but i want to add some more functionality to my form, this copying can create problem to user in the case of password.

Comment: possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-copy-paste-into-html-form-using-javascript

Comment: Again, if you're adding custom functionality and copy/pasting could cause an issue, that's *your* problem, not the users. Never try to solve your own problem by disadvantaging the user.

Comment: One of the first rules of UX is don't break default behaviors.

Comment: In the case of `type="password"` fields, some (most? all?) browsers don't let you _copy_ anyway. So if the user tries to copy from one password field to the next the results won't match and will immediately fail validation. If the user copies from some other source to paste into _both_ your password and confirm password fields then presumably that other source displayed the password in plain text and they knew it was correct. So what I'm saying is that in my opinion the whole thing is a bit of a non-issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You could disable `ctrl+v` combination and `right click` as well.**

for IE, you may tap into following event handlers:

```
onpaste="return false;" 
oncut="return false;" 
oncontextmenu="return false;" 
oncopy="return false;".
```

Here is a workaround for all browsers:

```
function noCTRL(e) {
      var code = (document.all) ? event.keyCode : e.which;
      var ctrl = (document.all) ? event.ctrlKey : e.modifiers & Event.CONTROL_MASK;
      var msg = "Sorry, this functionality is disabled.";
      if (document.all) {
        if (ctrl && code == 86) {
          //CTRL+V
          alert(msg);
          window.event.returnValue = false;
        } else if (ctrl && code == 67) { 
         //CTRL+C (Copy)
          alert(msg);
          window.event.returnValue = false;
        }
      } else {
        if (ctrl == 2) {
          //CTRL key
          alert(msg);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

In HTML section, your fields would look like:

```
Email :<input name="email" type="text" value=""/><br/>
Password :<input name="password" type="password" value=""/><br/>
Confirm Email :<input name="email" type="text" value="" onkeydown="return noCTRL(event)"/>    
Confirm Password :<input name="password" type="password" value="" onkeydown="return noCTRL(event)"/>
```

I don't think user can copy password fields if input type is `password`

Hope this helps.

**Note:**

1. Disabling JavaScript in browser will let users do whatever they want
2. Always Keep this in mind: respect user's freedom.

Comment: You *could* disable them. I would not say one *should* disable them.

Comment: This wasn't working for me in OSX.  The ctrl key is bound to '91' for example.  If you have access to a 'jquery' like library check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/catch-paste-input

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ yep I know, but this is the first search result when dealing with pasting in javascript, just giving people a route to another solution.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper lemme look into it

Answer (score 14):

### 2020 update

There are [`copy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event) and [`paste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) events you can use to prevent these actions, or to modify the data being copied or pasted. (see the links for browser support)

```html
<input type="text" onpaste="return false">
```

Or the longer javascript version:

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('nopaste');

elem.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="can paste"><br>
<input type="text" id="nopaste" placeholder="can not paste">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use onpaste. The paste event fires when the user attempts to paste text.

HTML

```
<h3>Play with this text area:</h3>
<textarea id="editor" rows="3">Try copying and pasting text into this field!</textarea>

<h3>Log:</h3>
<p id="log"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
function logCopy(event) {
  log.innerText = 'Copied!\n' + log.innerText;
}

function logPaste(event) {
  log.innerText = 'Pasted!\n' + log.innerText;
}

const editor = document.getElementById('editor');
const log = document.getElementById('log');

editor.oncopy = logCopy;
editor.onpaste = logPaste;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Copy**

```
document.addEventListener("copy", (e) => {
   console.log("copy")
});
```

**Paste**

```
document.addEventListener("paste", (e) => {
   console.log("paste")
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**2022 UPDATE:**

For Input Elements to receive onChange event on paste action, mention onpaste option as below

```
<input onpaste='return true' onChange={handleChange}/>
```