# how to disable paste in Ajax Html editor extender?

Tags: asp.net

I am using Asp text box with Ajax html editor extender. My issue is i don't want to allow to paste the content which is copied from some other source into my text box. And also in my text box when i am clicking the enter(for next line) it is stored as Div tag in my data base how to resolve these two issues. Please let me know the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [See Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-copy-paste-into-html-form-using-javascript)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input.disablecopypaste').bind('copy paste', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: See Update might helpful to you

Comment: Thank you Amol, it is working now. can you tell me the solution for my second issue?

Comment: Frankly I didn't understand "it is stored as Div tag in my data base"?

Comment: suppose i entered some data like "Hello world" and clicked enter button from key board for next line. then this is stored as "Hello world <Div>" in my data base. how to resolve this.?

Comment: You mean like <div>Hello world</div> ?

Comment: For that just add end with string before store to DB