# Restrict user from copying their own text written in input feild

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one input box for email on my website

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="box" id="email" value="Enter your email">
<input type="text" name="confirmEmail" class="box" id="confirmEmail" value="Enter your email again">
```

By using css below we can restrict user from selecting any content

```
 *{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    }
```

I wanted to know, is it possible to restrict user from copying their own written text in any input boxes? if yes how?
I want my users to write their email two time instead of copy paste.

Comment: I know you are looking for css solution but it's not possible, so closed as a JS duplicate(P.S this is tagged with JS as well, so that's another reason for me to close)

Comment: Why don't you just check if the two e-mail-addresses are equal instead of forcing the user to type it twice?

Comment: I think the usual belief is that if you copy and paste, there's nothing preventing you from copying a wrong email address. If you have to type it out twice, you're unlikely to make the same typo both times.

Comment: Use reference from this post -

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-copy-paste-into-html-form-using-javascript

Comment: I wonder why nobody has yet tried to force me to enter my name and address twice to check for typos...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of googling before posting here mate would be good...Anyway here is how to disable cut,copy and paste. Don't forget to include jQuery before the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#confirmEmail').live("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Validating an email with **[regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)** would help you for your scenario as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById("confirmEmail").addEventListener('paste',
    function(e){e.preventDefault()});

 document.getElementById("confirmEmail").addEventListener('drop',
   function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vPXrR/1/

**update**

```
 document.getElementById("email").addEventListener('paste',
     function(e){e.preventDefault()});
 document.getElementById("email").addEventListener('drop',
    function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vPXrR/2/

Comment: Preventing just the paste is a bad idea... A user can easily write their email address on the first field, select it , copy it, drag and drop it to the second field and then paste it to the first one... Disable cut + copy + paste to avoid the dodgy users...like me :D

Comment: Type the email address on the second field, copy it...paste it in the first one :D

Comment: @Thanos whew... now that was dodgy indeed :)

Comment: I've researched this specific issue with email validation, so i can tell you that you need all 3 cut-copy-paste disabled in both fields to be sure.Never assume your users will follow your logic, always validate and take in consideration this: You are creating something that will be used by monkeys which are supervised by donkeys :D

Comment: @Thanos he..he.. you got me at monkeys, yup now I ll be extra careful with any validation.