# disable right click on specific text field in javascript

Tags: javascript, textfield

Would like to disable right click or Ctrl C on a specific text field which is set to 'readonly'.

The value of this field is expected to be typed into another field without being copied and pasted.

Here is what I"ve:

```
<input onfocus="disableCaptchaCopy();" id="capId" type="text" value="<?php echo $gen_c; ?>" name="gen_c" readonly="readonly" />
```

Javascript function:

```
function disableCaptchaCopy() { 
    var capField = document.getElementsById(capId); 
    if (capField != null) {  
        field.oncut = function() { return false; }; 
    } 
}
```

Would be please if anyone could help out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict user from copying their own text written in input feild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566810/restrict-user-from-copying-their-own-text-written-in-input-feild)

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely valid but works in various different browsers including the latest versions of Firefox, IE and Chrome:

```
<input type="text" name="field" onpaste="return false" />
```

This doesn't prevent your text being copied, but it does prevent it being pasted into the subsequent field.