# How do I prevent cut copy pest event of password and confirm password field using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am having enrollment form with Almost 30 fields; for validating that form I am using angular
My validation is almost done. But having only concern about password and confirm password field.

How Do I prevent user from copy, cut, paste event of password and confirm password field using angular.

Comment: What kind of element are the fields?  `<input>`?

Comment: yes Input field. it is like 
<input type="password" required tabindex="8" />

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Copy/Paste into HTML form using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-copy-paste-into-html-form-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Cut, Copy and Paste function for textbox using AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783144/disable-cut-copy-and-paste-function-for-textbox-using-angularjs)

Comment: Yes it is (+1) - and that one has some good answers (vote to close as duplciate)

Answer (score 0):

i would try a couple of things

1st standard approeach, prevent default behavior and cancel event  on any right mouse button mouse down event and do the same for any key downn event with keyCode matching Ctrl or Command key.

2nd other event approach, watch for changes in the input field, ng-change and if the increase is bigger than 1 character, clean the model.

am sure there are other ways, but i think this are among the simplest ones