# Disable Cut, Copy and Paste function for textbox using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to disable copy paste in a textarea using angularJs. I tried to do so with ng-paste, like so:

Controller:

```
  angular.module('inputExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.val = '1';
  $scope.past = function() {

    console.log("d");
    $scope.val ="  ";

  }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<input ng-paste="past()" ng-model="val" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" name="anim" class="my-input" />
```

Input box has old data ( the initial paste data).

Blocking paste works the second time around, that is if I paste the data into input box, the data will be present, but on a second paste the data won't paste, *but* the old data value is not removed.

Comment: did you try return false in past function?

Answer (score 32):

Try making a directive that listens fot the `cut`, `copy`, and `paste` events and then prevent the default event action.

```
app.directive('stopccp', function(){
    return {
        scope: {},
        link:function(scope,element){
            element.on('cut copy paste', function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Use by adding the attribute to the input box.

```
<input stopccp ng-model="val" />
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/78toONWIxNreRNwopHEA?p=preview)</kbd>

You could also use the `ng-copy`, `ng-cut` and `ng-paste` directives and directly cancel the event.

```
<input ng-cut="$event.preventDefault()" ng-copy="$event.preventDefault()" ng-paste="$event.preventDefault()" ng-model="val" />
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RADVZjMAT8La62GgJSK1?p=previeww)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks you quantumwannabe

Answer (score 21):

The simplest way:

```
<input ng-paste="$event.preventDefault();" placeholder='You cannot past here'>
```

Working [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/94Cs5Xxl7VLp3m9J2t3Z?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this;

 <input type="text" ng-paste="paste($event)" ng-model="name"/>
```

In Controller

```
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.paste = function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       return false
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {....
.......
$scope.past = function() {
   $timeout(function() {
      $scope.val = " ";
   }, 0);
}...
```

here is the [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/trw6pGrSjYRblOKDKhrU?p=preview)