# Using ngPaste with Angular Formly

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-formly

I'm using Angular Formly to build a simple form.

I need to disable paste in one of the input fields. Earlier, I disable ng-Paste default event as described in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27783611/3156644

But, since the form generation is now done by Formly, how do I conditionally add the directives with the functions($event.preventDefault) in to the fields generated by Formly?

One option I can think of is creating a new template, but that doesn't seem like DRY code. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending an existing template looks DRY enough for me:

```
formlyConfig.setType({
  name: 'nopaste-input',
  extends: 'input', // Extend regular input
  link: function(scope, el, attrs) {}, // Add functionality here
  // etc...
});
```

Custom template docs: http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/custom-templates#creating-a-custom-template

Bootstrap Types: https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap/tree/master/src/types