# How to intercept COMMAND+V on OSX Safarii?

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, paste

I have a function I use to intercept CTRL+V and COMMAND+V:

```
    function paste() {
        clip.val('').focus();
        //wait until Browser insert text to textarea
        self.oneTime(100, function() {
            self.insert(clip.val());
            clip.blur().val('');
        });
    }
```

clip is hidden textarea, right now it's hidden using black div on top of it (the only way I found to fix Andorid). And in keydown event I call that function:

```
} else if (e.which === 86) {
    //CTRL+V
    paste();
    return true; // I return true because I have return false at the end
                 // of keydown event
}
```

But seems that it don't work on MacOSX Safari as you can check in this [issue on github](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/issues/3). Anybody know why is that happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-copy-paste-into-html-form-using-javascript

Comment: @Nit thanks for the link, will check onpaste event.

Comment: @Nit I've used onpaste but it don't work at all in FireFox, work in Chrome.

Comment: I've tested the linked answer both on OS X Firefox & Safari and it works just fine. Either you've implemented the linked answer wrong or your problem lies elsewhere in your code logic.

Comment: @Nit created the code using paste event again and it work also in FF.