# How to disable Copy, Paste into HTML form using Php

Tags: php

I want to prevent people from pasting password in login form. Is it possible by PHP to disable the ability to paste into input fields.

Comment: You can't do this by `PHP` because its a server side language. You have to use `Javascript/Jquery` for this.

Comment: What in all of Earth are you trying to do with this? Stop people from using password managers and consequently encourage them to use a weak password just so they can remember it or type it easily?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Copy/Paste into HTML form using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-copy-paste-into-html-form-using-javascript)

Comment: ok i got it. thanks to everybody

Comment: does any answer helped you? if so please mark the correct answer which helped you to solve the problem. this way we can improve the stackoverflow community. please

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do this with `HTML` by adding some properties to `input`.

> I don't know why you want to use `PHP` for this.

```html
<input type="test" onCopy="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" onPaste="return false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code
HTML

```
<input type="password" id="pwd">

Jquery 

 $('#pwd').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

In Jquery you can do like this to disable copy paste on whole Page

```
$('body').bind('copy paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to disable paste in your input as follows:

html:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="myInput" />
```

javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
 var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
 myInput.onpaste = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it using php, because it is server side scripting language. you will have to handle this situation using **javascript** or **Jquery**

Following are the options which can help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#txtInput').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      });
    });



jQuery('input.disablePaste').keydown(function(event) {
    var forbiddenKeys = new Array('c', 'x', 'v');
    var keyCode = (event.keyCode) ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    var isCtrl;
    isCtrl = event.ctrlKey
    if (isCtrl) {
        for (i = 0; i < forbiddenKeys.length; i++) {
            if (forbiddenKeys[i] == String.fromCharCode(keyCode).toLowerCase()) {
                 return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#password').bind("cut copy paste", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="password">
```