# How can I disable Chrome paste menu on touch?

Tags: google-chrome

I am developing an app to run in Chrome (47.0.2526.106 m)  and use a 3rd party keyboard.  Chrome presents a small paste menu when you touch a text field.  Does anyone know how this can be disabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an [HTML Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-copy-paste-into-html-form-using-javascript/26255397#26255397) to each input to solve this problem. If you don't like this solution, you can also use JavaScript to achieve what you are looking for.