# How to Prevent/disable copy and paste in Tinymce

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I am setting up the tinymce on my system, and want to disable the copy and paste for the user in the tinymce editor, but no where I find the solution. How can I disable the copy paste in tinymce

I have implemented the 
[Disable pasting text into HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-pasting-text-into-html-form)
But it is working only in simple text area but not in tinymce textarea

```
<script>
// Register onpaste on inputs and textareas in browsers that don't
// natively support it.
(function () {
    var onload = window.onload;

    window.onload = function () {
        if (typeof onload == "function") {
            onload.apply(this, arguments);
        }

        var fields = [];
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            fields.push(inputs[i]);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
            fields.push(textareas[i]);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            var field = fields[i];

            if (typeof field.onpaste != "function" && !!field.getAttribute("onpaste")) {
                field.onpaste = eval("(function () { " + field.getAttribute("onpaste") + " })");
            }

            if (typeof field.onpaste == "function") {
                var oninput = field.oninput;

                field.oninput = function () {
                    if (typeof oninput == "function") {
                        oninput.apply(this, arguments);
                    }

                    if (typeof this.previousValue == "undefined") {
                        this.previousValue = this.value;
                    }

                    var pasted = (Math.abs(this.previousValue.length - this.value.length) > 1 && this.value != "");

                    if (pasted && !this.onpaste.apply(this, arguments)) {
                        this.value = this.previousValue;
                    }

                    this.previousValue = this.value;
                };

                if (field.addEventListener) {
                    field.addEventListener("input", field.oninput, false);
                } else if (field.attachEvent) {
                    field.attachEvent("oninput", field.oninput);
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
</script>       

    </head>
    <body>
<!-- Not Working here-->
        <textarea class="tinymce" onpaste="return false;"></textarea>

        <!-- javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/tinymce/init-tinymce.js"></script>

<!-- Working here-->        
<textarea onpaste="return false;"></textarea>



    </body>
```

I expect that, it should work in the textarea of tinymce,

Thank you in advance, I will be very gratefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to prevent the default

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

I also read that you can intercept paste in the `tinymce.init`

```
paste_preprocess: function(plugin, args) {
    console.log(args.content);
    args.content = '';
  }
```

Hope that one of those methods works out for you

Comment: Thank you so much Poopy Doop, your second code answer: 'paste_preprocess' is working perfectly. I help me a lot

Comment: @madarauchiha please read the [How to Prevent/Disable Copy and Paste in Tinymce](https://blog.pooripadhai.com/prevent-disable-copy-paste-in-tinymce/) and download the source file from there. Hope you will get the solution. Let me know if you have any other issue.