# jquery on paste event not working in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

On paste event is not working in mobile browser.
Code:

```js
$('#textboxmyid').bind("paste", function (e) {e.preventDefault();});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textboxmyid">
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to prevent people from pasting?

Comment: What have you investigated? Does it work in an other Browser?

Comment: Make them type their password twice @Ivar, just a guess but that is what I have used it for no use having them confirm they typed the correct pw if just copy paste it.

Comment: @Scath In that case, [have](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/password-pasting) [some](https://www.troyhunt.com/the-cobra-effect-that-is-disabling/) [read](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131106/is-there-any-reason-to-disable-paste-password-on-login) on why you never should do that. (Same applies for thinks [like emails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1725500)).

Comment: @JeroenHeier yes it work on desktop laptop but in mobile it not work, i need amount validation input