# Disable paste in Formik Field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a number of Formik Field(s) in a FieldArray.
I would need to prevent the user from pasting text in to the field.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass directly to the input the property `onPaste` and either `return false` or call `event.preventDefault`.

```
<input onPaste={() => return false} />
```

OR

```
<input onPaste={e => e.preventDefault()} />
```

But this have some browser compatibility problems.

You can relate to the [javascript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-pasting-text-into-html-form) of this, the only difference is that in react you pass `onPaste` instead of `onpaste`.