# Is there a function to prevent pasting text in google form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a google form for an upcoming quiz, and I'm trying to prevent pasting text input for answers and spelling check. What are the correct functionality codes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable pasting text into HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-pasting-text-into-html-form)

Comment: You cannot add such checks to fields inside Google Forms

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to prevent pasting text in Google Form.

You can try to create an [extension](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/forms) or you can request for it to be added using the Send Feedback feature on Google Forms:

- You have to go to the [Forms main page](https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/?tgif=d)
- On the burger menu on the top right, click on the option of `Help & Feedback`
- Once there click `Send Feedback`

Comment: Server side Addons can't do that either.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such feature. Consider sending Google feedback for such a feature request. Alternatively,  create your own form.

Related: [Disable pasting text into HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-pasting-text-into-html-form)