# Disable copy paste in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

I have my input Textbox like below. User should not be allowed to perform copy paste in the Textbox. But somehow my code is not working. Is there any other approach?

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="startTextbox1" appOnlynumber onkeypress='validate(event)' onCopy="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" onPaste="return false" formControlName="startTextbox1">
```

I have also written custom directive like it specified in below link but its not working.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u4jcam?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you are going for, but perhaps this prior question gives you some place to start:

[Disable pasting text into HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-pasting-text-into-html-form)

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do this with JS / jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#startTextbox1').on("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Hope that can help

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```html
<Input onPaste="return false" onCopy="return false" placeholder="Try to copy or paste here" />
```