# How to prevent text from being pasted in TextField with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and trying to write a program to prevent text from being copied into textfield.  the following is my code

```
function dontpaste()
{
  alert("hello");
  return true;
}

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" onpaste="dontpaste()">
```

The method is getting called. But the text gets copied after alert.
Even

```
document.getElementById('name').value="";
```

is not working.
Even tried with

```
return false;
```

for the method, still the text gets copied.

What needs to be done so that the method is called but text is not copied?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Similar to sites that disable right-clicking, behaviors like these only serve to annoy — they're trivial to disable by the user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable pasting text into HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-pasting-text-into-html-form)  see  this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8797443/9977151   you can pass `event` to `dontpaste` and then use `preventDefault`

Answer (score 1):

This won't pass the event parameter doing it like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" onpaste="dontpaste()">
```

Change it to

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
document.getElementById("name").addEventListener("paste", dontpaste);
```

then use event.preventDefault(); inside dontpaste function to block the default paste functionality.

Working example where paste doesn't work.

```js
function dontpaste(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
}

document.getElementById("name").addEventListener("paste", dontpaste);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
```

Comment: *technically* you can still get at the event via `this.event.preventDefault()`. But that's a bit gross.